# Implementing The input as a separate thread

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an ACTION_MOVE input that moves a paddle as long as the screen is touched, in place of the ACTION_DOWN that is currently present. However Once I switch the ACTION_MOVE in place of ACTION_DOWN, the paddle moves but with stutters(some times too slow, then stopping then going too fast all of a sudden). How would I resolve this? Would Moving the Input to another thread be any good?

Here's the code

MainActivity.java

```
package com.nblsoft.ballpractise;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View myball = new BallDraw(this);
        myball.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

        setContentView(myball);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

BallDraw.java

```
package com.nblsoft.ballpractise;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;



public class BallDraw extends View {

    //Default System Variables

    int screenHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

    private int xMin = 0;          // This view's bounds
    private int xMax;
    private int yMin = 0;
    private int yMax;


    //Game Variables

    public int ball_pos_x = 0;
    public int ball_pos_y = 800;
    public int ball_vel_x = 5;
    public int ball_vel_y = 5;
    public int pad_1_pos = 10;
    public int pad_2_pos = 10;
    public int randi=1;
    //Pads Implemented as Array of points
    //public int[] pad_1 = {100,200,220,240};
    //public int[] pad_2 = {100,200,1250,1270};

    Rect pad_1 = new Rect(400 + pad_1_pos,220,500 + pad_1_pos,240);
    Rect pad_2 = new Rect(400 + pad_2_pos,1250,500 + pad_1_pos,1270);

    Rect pad_1_touch = new Rect(0, 0, 1080, 200);
    Rect pad_2_touch = new Rect(0, 1300, 1080, 1500);


    //calculations for screen sizes



    private Paint paint;


    public BallDraw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();

        // To enable touch mode
        this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                if(pad_1_touch.contains(x,y)){
                    //pad_1[0]+=10;
                    //pad_1[1]+=10;

                    pad_1.offset(pad_1_pos,0);

                }
                else if(pad_2_touch.contains(x,y)){
                    //pad_2[0]+=10;
                    //pad_2[1]+=10;

                    pad_2.offset(pad_2_pos,0);
                }

        }
        return true; //Event Handled

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        //Touch Regions (Un-comment to see touch Regions)
        //canvas.drawRect(pad_1_touch,paint);
        //canvas.drawRect(pad_2_touch,paint);

        //Draw Border
        canvas.drawRect(0,800,1080,803,paint);

        //Paddles Draw code
        canvas.drawRect(pad_1,paint);
        canvas.drawRect(pad_2,paint);
        //canvas.drawRect(pad_1[0],pad_1[2], pad_1[1], pad_1[3], paint);
        //canvas.drawRect(pad_2[0],pad_2[2],pad_2[1],pad_2[3],paint);

        //Ball code
        canvas.drawRect(ball_pos_x,ball_pos_y,ball_pos_x + 13, ball_pos_y+13,paint);

        // Update the position of the ball, including collision detection and reaction.
        update();

        // Delay
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
        // Set the movement bounds for the ball
        xMax = w-1;
        yMax = h-1;
    }

    private void update(){

        ball_pos_y += ball_vel_y;
        ball_pos_x += ball_vel_x;

        if(pad_1.contains(ball_pos_x,ball_pos_y)){
            ball_vel_y = -ball_vel_y;

        }
        else if(pad_2.contains(ball_pos_x,ball_pos_y)){
            ball_vel_y = -ball_vel_y;

        }
        else if(ball_pos_x >= xMax){
            ball_vel_x = -ball_vel_x;
        }
        else if(ball_pos_y >= yMax){
            ball_init();
        }
        else if(ball_pos_x <= 0){
            ball_vel_x = -ball_vel_x;
        }
        else if(ball_pos_y <= 0){
            ball_init();
        }

    }

    private void ball_init(){
        if (randi == 1){
            randi = -1;
        }
        else{
            randi= 1;
        }

        ball_pos_x=0;
        ball_pos_y=800;
        ball_vel_x=5;
        ball_vel_y=5 * randi;

    }



}
```

Comment: The touch events arrive on the main UI thread. Sending them to another thread isn't going to change that. You need to determine the cause of the stutters, e.g. is your rendering or computation code taking too long. You should start by getting rid of the sleep call in `onDraw()` -- sleeping on the main UI thread is never a good idea.

Comment: Tried removing the entire try-catch block from onDraw(). No use. The stutter only occurs with the paddles. The paddles move with hiccups while the ball keeps on moving normally.

Comment: If the ball is moving smoothly, then the problem is either with the way you are moving the paddle or with the way you are handling events. It sounds like the paddle is not moving the same amount each frame, or not moving every frame; do you know which it is? You said you were moving the paddle while the finger was in contact with the screen, but ACTION_DOWN is only supposed to fire when a finger first touches. For Android Breakout I used ACTION_MOVE and had the paddle chase the finger, but it could have limited the amount of motion per frame.

Comment: The code Works with ACTION_DOWN but i Have to keep tapping the screen to move it. If I replace it with ACTION_MOVE the paddle starts stuttering.
I'm Sorry for not explaining this earlier. I have edited the post to reflect this.